# Boxes too narrow and cursor sometimes invisible in Chromium

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium

I’m using `Version 60.0.3112.113 (Developer Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on LinuxMint 18 (64-bit)`, the latest version in the Linux Mint 18 repository, but since version 60, I’ve faced the problem that on a lot of websites (Trello, Twitter, Facebook, xkcd, and many more) boxes are displayed strangely as if some vertical margin or padding at the top were missing and the cursor is often invisible in text fields (for example the one I’m typing into right now).

I’ve tried resetting my profile, using a fresh one, using the incognito mode with all extension deactivated, etc. Nothing changed anything.

[image: The error on xkcd]

[image: The error on Facebook]

[image: The error on Trello]

Thank you!

Comment: did you configures any font? or any other GUI settings in Ubuntu? Try to uninstall, then delete user folders, then reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to Biswa in the comments! Inspired by the comment, I found out that the websites looked normal when I edited out Helvetica, and indeed, I had a copy of Helvetica installed (have had it there for a long time though). A few other typefaces seem to have caused problems as well.

1. I removed them all (`mv ~/.fonts [some other place]`),
2. ran `fc-cache -v` (with and without `sudo`, not sure which did the trick),
3. restarted Chromium,

and now it’s all working again!

Comment: Want to know more. Expand your answer with more details. Like how you remove them all? what is the full syntax of `fc-cache` command you used?

Comment: @Biswa I’ve expanded the answer. (But the `-v` flag only makes the output verbose.)